# View grants in MySQL

Tags: mysql

How do I view the grants (access rights) for a given user in MySQL?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

```
mysql> show grants for 'user'@'host'
```

Comment: `SHOW GRANTS` if you are only interested in the current user.

Answer (score 36):

An alternative method for recent versions of MySQL is:

```
select * from information_schema.user_privileges where grantee like "'user'%";
```

The possible advantage with this format is the increased flexibility to check "user's" grants from any host (assuming consistent user names) or to check for specific privileges with additional conditions (eg, privilege_type = 'delete').

This version is probably better suited to use within a script while the "show grants" syntax is better for interactive sessions (more "human readable").

Comment: +1 : This allows checking against tables and particular privileges as well, which is useful in some cases (rather than just a textual description as returned by SHOW GRANTS).

Comment: This is also very helpful for debugging improperly created grants.  It can be difficult to get what you need from SHOW GRANTS if your granted for the wrong user or host;

Comment: Don't forget about the other grants related tables SCHEMA_PRIVILEGES, TABLE_PRIVILEGES and even COLUMN_PRIVILEGES

Answer (score 8):

You could try this:

```
SELECT GRANTEE, PRIVILEGE_TYPE FROM information_schema.user_privileges;
SELECT User,Host,Db FROM mysql.db;
```

Comment: I think this is **the best query** to find *what grants have all users* 

Answer (score 5):

You might want to check out mk-show-grants from [Maatkit](http://www.maatkit.org/), which will output the current set of grants for all users in a canonical form, making version control or replication more straightforward.

Answer (score 1):

If you're already running a web server with PHP then [phpMyAdmin](http://www.phpmyadmin.net/) is a fairly friendly administrative tool.

Comment: ah-ha! When phpMyAdmin is installed, that makes grants much easier! Great tip :-)

Answer (score 1):

You may need to [Show Grants Statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/show-grants.html)

```
SHOW GRANTS [FOR user]
```

This statement displays the privileges that are assigned to a MySQL user account, in the form of GRANT statements that must be executed to duplicate the privilege assignments.

To display the privileges granted to the current user (the account you are using to connect to the server), you can use any of the following statements:

```
SHOW GRANTS;
SHOW GRANTS FOR CURRENT_USER;
SHOW GRANTS FOR CURRENT_USER();
```

**note:**
SHOW GRANTS requires the SELECT privilege for the mysql system database, except to display privileges for the current user.\

It's directly from the official website