# Does a standard mysql script exist that gives you a list of mysql users permissions?

Tags: mysql, permissions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [View grants in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/127679/view-grants-in-mysql)

Is there a canned script that can list the databases a mysql user has access to and the rights he's got, or given a database, a list of users with rights to it and what those rights are?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  SHOW GRANTS FOR CURRENT_USER;
```

Will show your Current Users privilege on all databases.

```
  SHOW GRANTS FOR USERNAME;
```

Will do the same for a particular user.

Answer (score 1):

The information_schema.schema_privileges table gives this information:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/schema-privileges-table.html